# How do I restrict the values of a parameter for this HTML helper method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-like, html-helper

I made a html helper for the facebook like button.

```
public static MvcHtmlString FacebookLike(this HtmlHelper helper, bool send, bool showFaces, string layout, string href = null, int width = 450)
{
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.AddCssClass("fb-like");
    div.MergeAttribute("data-send", send.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-width", width.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-show-faces", showFaces.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-layout", layout);
    if (href != null)
    {
        div.MergeAttribute("data-href", href);
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString());
}
```

The layout parameter only has 3 possible values (standard, button_count and box_count). My question is how can I make this only accept those 3 values?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it an `enum`:

```
public enum LayoutType
{
    standard,
    button_count,
    box_count
}
```

and then change your method a bit:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FacebookLike(this HtmlHelper helper, bool send, bool showFaces, LayoutType layout, string href = null, int width = 450)
{
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.AddCssClass("fb-like");
    div.MergeAttribute("data-send", send.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-width", width.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-show-faces", showFaces.ToString());
    div.MergeAttribute("data-layout", Enum.GetName(typeof(LayoutType), layout));
    if (href != null)
    {
        div.MergeAttribute("data-href", href);
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString());
}
```

note the signature now uses the `enum` and the `data-layout` is set by grabbing the name of the `enum` passed in.

Comment: +1 simple enough, but the enum should be singular: `LayoutType` and it's members should be Pascal without underscores. Don't mean to nag.

Comment: @Silvermind, the purpose of not making them **Pascal cased** (because I generally would) is to make it extremely straight forward to get the selected `enum` value into the proper `string` value for `data-layout`. As far as it being singular, that's fine, I've modified it as such since most `enum`'s are singular.